# How many people each do Batman and Superman kill in BVS: Dawn of Justice?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

One common criticism of *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* is that Batman and Superman kill a lot of people. Having watched it, I can confirm that this is very true.

But how many did they each kill?

Here are some guidelines:

1. If you can't tell whether someone died or not, use common sense. If a mook gets thrown through several walls or caught in an explosion, we can assume they're dead.
2. If, for example, Batman purposely pushes a mook so that said mook shoots someone, it still counts as Batman's kill.
3. Kills from dreams/visions/etc. don't count.
4. Totally indirect killings such as Batman's brandings causing murder in prisons also do not count.
5. Ordering someone to kill for you counts.

I know some companion material stated that Batman doesn't kill, but that clearly isn't true, so ignore that.

Comment: One problem with this question is that I don't want to watch it again to find out

Comment: As many as they had to.

Comment: How to say, specifically in batman's fight where there are survival chances.

Comment: How do we know for certain that someone(non-lethal shots i.e. heat-vision through torso, headshot from bullets) died?

Comment: Batman killed a lot of people in dream sequences, and there may have been some collateral damage chasing the kryptonite, but I can't recall him directly killing anyone.

Comment: @DCShannon Collateral damage counts. Plus, he shot at least one person and stabbed at least one through the chest with a knife.

Comment: Ah yeah, he killed a guy when he rescued Martha, right? There was so much awesome in that movie I don't remember every scene. Definitely need to go see it again.

Comment: http://screenrant.com/batman-v-superman-kills/ + http://www.heyuguys.com/exclusive-zack-snyder-explains-detail-dark-knight-kills-batman-v-superman/ + http://www.geekcrusade.com/news/batman-v-superman-batman-body-count/25371

Comment: @amaranth well..... you've corected it it seems.... no need to whine in a comment :P

Answer (score 4):

According to this video, Batman killed **21** people, not counting the kills he made in his Darkseid dream.

A similar video for Superman has yet to be released.